# Is there a specific name for an airport gate at ground level?

Tags: airport-design

At a two level airport most gates are located on the upper level with loading bridges or jetways. Is there a specific name for gates located on the lower level (ground) for like use of turbo prop airliners or small jets that do not use a jetway?

Comment: Cargo/luggage gate?

Answer (score 3):

As you have pointed out, some airports have gates located at two levels. The upper gates have a jetway leading to the entry door of the aircraft. The lower gates (sometimes referred to colloquially as "ground level" [or similar] **gates**) exit directly onto the ramp whereupon passengers walk to the aircraft.

In my experience, for terminology consistency and ease of passenger terminal navigation, both lower and upper gates are all shown on airport departure/arrival monitors, boarding passes, etc., as "Gates."

Of course, there may be some airports that use a different naming convention (between upper and lower gates) but I have never encountered that.

Comment: Thank you for your answer 757tonga.

Answer (score 1):

The parking spot of the aircraft on the ramp is commonly called a "stand".
The exit to the ramp (either directly to the aircraft via a jetbridge or to say a bus stop) is typically called a gate.

That's internationally accepted terminology, but I can't guarantee that there aren't airports or countries where other words are used (especially if languages other than English are the norm there, obviously).